# R markdown - set options for LaTeX packages

Tags: r, knitr, bookdown

If I set an output parameter in .Rmd file in following way:

```
output:
   bookdown::pdf_book:
    base_format: rticles::elsevier_article
    keep_tex: true
```

in the produced .tex file, *endfloat* package will be used with option 'nomarkers'. In other words, following line will be included in produced .tex file:

```
\usepackage[nomarkers]{endfloat}
```

How can I set options for LaTeX packages used by the output?

In my example, I wish to set endfloat options to 'markers', so that mentioned line in .tex file will looks as follows:

```
\usepackage[markers]{endfloat}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution

```
header-includes:
   - \usepackage[markers]{endfloat}
output:
   bookdown::pdf_book:
    base_format: rticles::elsevier_article
    keep_tex: true
```

works not, because there are package conflicts. The other solution I tried and worked, was to download the package from GitHub https://github.com/rstudio/rticles and change the file template.tex to your needs. This file is located in `/inst/rmarkdown/templates/elsevier_article/resources/`. For me this worked and the .tex file has the desired output as you expect it.

Comment: Is it possible to store in different location amended copy of the template, so that I will not touch the original? How can I tell R! to use my local copy?